# Scala, Elasticsearch the new RestHighLevelClient and BulkProcessor

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch-6

In my Scala project, I'm trying to change the old transportClient with the new RestHighLevelClient for connecting to Elasticsearch (6.1).

But I have a problem when try to create a BulkProcessor, I don't know how to convert this example from Java to Scala

```
`BulkProcessor.Builder builder = BulkProcessor.builder(client::bulkAsync, listener);`
```

my code is this:

```
val client=new RestHighLevelClient(
  RestClient.builder(
    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http") ) )

val builder: BulkProcessor.Builder =BulkProcessor.builder(client, listener)
```

But I obtain this error:

```
 overloaded method value builder with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: java.util.function.BiConsumer[org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest,org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener[org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse]],x$2: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.Listener)org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.Builder <and>
[error]   (x$1: org.elasticsearch.client.Client,x$2: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.Listener)org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.Builder
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient, org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.Listener)
[error]   val builder: BulkProcessor.Builder =BulkProcessor.builder(client, listener)
```

If I try to convert "`client::bulkAsync`" with "`client.bulkAsync _`" or "`client::bulkAsync(_._._)`" obtain other error:

```
type mismatch;
[error] found   : org.apache.http.Header*
[error] required: org.apache.http.Header
[error] var bulkProcessor =BulkProcessor.builder(client.bulkAsync(_,_,_),listener)
```

This is the method bulkAsync in Java:

```
 public final void bulkAsync(BulkRequest bulkRequest, ActionListener<BulkResponse> listener, Header... headers) {
```

Did anyone use RestHighLevelClient and BulkProcessor in Scala? or know how fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

Scala 2.11 doesn't have good interoperability with Java 8 functions interface.
create BiConsumerId(accepts two input arguments and returns no result) should solve the issue :

```
val bulkAsyncAsJava :  BiConsumer[BulkRequest, ActionListener[BulkResponse]] = new BiConsumer[BulkRequest, ActionListener[BulkResponse]] {
  override def accept(bulkRequest : BulkRequest , actionListener:ActionListener[BulkResponse]): Unit = {
    restHighLevelClient.bulkAsync(bulkRequest, actionListener)
  }
}
val bulkProcessor = BulkProcessor.builder(bulkAsyncAsJava, new BulkProcessor.Listener() {
override def beforeBulk(executionId: Long, request: BulkRequest): Unit = {
}

override

def afterBulk(executionId: Long, request: BulkRequest, response: BulkResponse): Unit = {
}

override

def afterBulk(executionId: Long, request: BulkRequest, failure: Throwable): Unit = {
}}).build
```

Comment: Missing one parameter in ElasticSearch 7.1: `restHighLevelClient.bulkAsync(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT, actionListener)`